# WIX: Change the add/remove program icon does not work

Tags: .net, wix

the way shown here http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html does not work

I put this

```
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="..\Resource\logo.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

in the Product> section but I get the error

> Error 3   Schema validation failed with the following error at line 1, column 631: The element 'Product' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' has invalid child element 'Icon' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'. List of possible elements expected: 'Package'. C:\Users\user\Documents\svnRepos\prjs\Mold Sentinel\trunk\software\Mold Sentinel Control App\Installer\Product.wxs  13  1   Installer

I wonder how to specify the source path ... supposedly it starts from the path where the exe file is created, right?

Thanks much

Comment: The error is not complaining about the path, it's complaining about the structure of the XML itself.

Answer (score 4):

The document you've [linked to](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html) is *slightly* incorrect in stating:

> These two elements can be placed *anywhere* in your WiX project under the Product element.

(My *emphasis*)

Since if we look at the `Product` element's [schema documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/product.html), we see:

> **Children**
>
> - Sequence (min: 1, max: 1)
> - - Package (min: 1, max: 1)
> - - Choice of elements (min: 0, max: unbounded)
> - - - AppId (min: 0, max: unbounded)
>
> [snipped]
>
> - - - Icon (min: 0, max: unbounded)

So, the *one* place you cannot put these elements within the `Product` element is *before the `Package` element*.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the very informative answer which link the correct documentation! My next question about the SourceFile argument of the Icon. Where this path starts for? is it related to the application path itself? Or to the intalaltion path? how WINX elaborate paths?